# Java DOM: How to get how many child elements

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML Document:

```
<entities xmlns="urn:yahoo:cap">
    <entity score="0.988">
        <text end="4" endchar="4" start="0" startchar="0">Messi</text>
        <wiki_url>http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Lionel_Messi</wiki_url>
        <types>
            <type region="us">/person</type>
        </types>
    </entity>
</entities>
```

I have a `TreeMap<String,String> data` which stores the `getTextContent()` for both the `"text"` and `"wiki_url"` element. Some `"entity"`s will only have the `"text"` element (no `"wiki_url"`) so i need a way of finding out when there is only the text element as the child and when there is a `"wiki_url"`. I could use `document.getElementByTag("text")` & `document.getElementByTag("wiki_url")` but then I would lose the relationship between the text and the url.

I'm trying to get the amount of elements within the `"entity"` element by using:

```
NodeList entities = document.getElementsByTagName("entity"); //List of all the entity nodes
int nchild; //Number of children
System.out.println("Number of entities: "+ entities.getLength()); //Prints 1 as expected
nchild=entities.item(0).getChildNodes().getLength(); //Returns 7
```

However as shows above this returns 7 (which I don't understand, surely its 3 or 4 if you include the grandchild)
I was then going to use the number of children to cycle through them all to check if `getNodeName().equals("wiki_url")` and save it to data if correct.

Why is it that i am getting the number of children as 7 when I can only count 3 children and 1 grandchild?

Comment: It sounds like you're only interested in *element* child nodes... which isn't the same as *all* child nodes.

Comment: Does the text inside each element count as a child too? thats the only way i can get the number 7

Comment: Yes - text nodes are still nodes. The easiest way to see this is to iterate over the child nodes and print out their types...

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white-spaces following `>` of `<entity score="0.988">` also count for nodes, similarly end of line chararcter between the tags are also parsed to nodes. If you are interested in a particular node with a name, add a helper method like below and call wherever you want.

```
Node getChild(final NodeList list, final String name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
        {
            final Node node = list.item(i);
            if (name.equals(node.getNodeName()))
            {
                return node;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and call

```
final NodeList childNodes = entities.item(0).getChildNodes();
final Node textNode = getChild(childNodes, "text");
final Node wikiUrlNode = getChild(childNodes, "wiki_url");
```

Normally when working with DOM, comeup with helper methods like above to simplify main processing logic.

Comment: For the sake of tidiness I'd make `getChild` take a Node, rather than a NodeList and call `GetChildNodes()` inside the method; no reason the caller should need to do that.

Comment: Thanks this fixed everything!